# Pattern match Scala case class capturing one field only

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a match statement against a case class with a large number of fields. Am I able to capture one of the fields by name and ignore the rest without specifying the other ones in position with underscores? This is particularly hard to do when what I want is deeply nested.

Here's what I have right now:

```scala
record match {
  case MyRecordType(_, _, _, MyNestedType(_, _, namedFieldAsVar, _), _, _, _) => 
    doStuffWith(namedFieldAsVar)
```

I would like to do something like this:

```scala
record match {
  case MyRecordType { nested = MyNestedType { namedFieldAsVar } } => 
    doStuffWith(namedFieldAsVar)
}
```

Other languages support this kind of pattern matching like this below (Rust), does Scala offer something similar?

```rust
match record {
  MyRecordType { named_field_as_var, .. } => do_stuff_with(named_field_as_var)
}
```

Comment: Not, sadly **Scala** doesn't have this feature. You can do this: `case record: MyRecordType => doStuff(record.nested.namedFieldAsVar)`.

Comment: I figured that would be the case. Would've been nice not to follow a line of dots. Thanks!

Comment: ticket of record is https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/6524

Comment: I don't see how it's possible either. not sure if this applies in your case, but there are some point of views that say having too nested records is a code smell and we should try to refactor out. other than this, I know lenses help managing nested case classes, have you looked at it? https://julien-truffaut.github.io/Monocle/

Comment: monocle has moved to: https://github.com/optics-dev/Monocle